# Как заменить первую букву каждой строки на заглавную?

Tags: shell

Есть текстовый файл со строками.
Как заменить первую букву каждой строки на заглавную?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С использованием GNU sed:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\u&/' file > result
```

С использованием awk:

```
awk '{ print toupper(substr($0, 1, 1)) substr($0, 2) }' file > result
```

С использованием powershell (у файла может потребоваться указать кодировку, например, `cat -enc utf8`):

```
cat file | %{ write ($_.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + $_.Substring(1)) } > result
```